# sorting a file content by column

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file which has formed by grepping contents from multiple files in directory. The content of the file is such:

```
14:59:12,398 254900 269 112
14:59:14,457 255000 169
14:59:18,517 255100 69
12:46:21,196 11000 192127
```

How do i sort the file by the first column (which is actually the timestamp) using Unux commands?  Note that each row may have different number of entries/columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort file
```

would do this.

`sort` will by default use the whole line as the sorting key, which means that it would use the first column and then the rest of the contents on that line if needed.

If you'd like to sort explicitly on the first whitespace-delimited column:

```
sort -k1,1 file
```

This will *only* use the first column for sorting.  Add `-s` before the filename to make `sort` use a "stable" sorting algorithm, meaning it would not change the order of lines that have identical keys from what it was in the input.

This assumes that the timestamp uses zero-filled (or space-indented) numbers for hours less than 10.  If that is not the case, use `sort -n` or `sort -k1,1n` for numeric sorting.